# How can I record audio to wav format?

Tags: windows-10, audio-recording, wav

When I use Voice Recorder, it always saves it as a `.m4a`, but I need the file as a `.wav`.

I know it is possible using Sound Recorder in Windows 7, but Windows 10 seems to use a different program.

Is there a way of doing this natively in Windows 10?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any particular reason you want to do this natively? Otherwise I can recommend [Audacity](http://www.audacityteam.org/download/). It allows you to record audio files among others. The option to save to wav is found in the file/export audio menu. Furthermore Audacity is free software, so that should not keep you from using it.

Comment: I actually now think I need to the files to be saved as PCM .. I want to save them as resources and play them from a c# application

Comment: @Bassie If you want PCM coding, then [WAV *is* what you want](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV#WAV_file_audio_coding_formats_compared).

Answer (score -5):

To make wav from Windows 10 voice recorder, first record sound then right click file and choose open file location then rename giving it a wav extension. You should get (if you change a file name extension, the file might become unusable.  Are you sure you want to change it?  Click Yes.
It's now a wav file.

Comment: But it doesn't work if you play it as a .wav file